# How to scrape and extract data from JSON file?

Tags: python, json, selenium, web-scraping, python-requests

I try to extract all the data for every school on the following site:

https://schulfinder.kultus-bw.de/

My code is this:

```py
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import json

url = "https://schulfinder.kultus-bw.de/api/school?uuid=81af189c-7bc0-44a3-8c9f-73e6d6e50fdb&_=1675072758525"

payload = {}
headers = {}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Output is this:

```json
{
  "outpost_number": "0",
  "name": "Gartenschule Grundschule Ebnat",
  "street": "Abt-Angehrn-Str.",
  "house_number": "5",
  "postcode": "73432",
  "city": "Aalen",
  "phone": "+49736796700",
  "fax": "+497367967016",
  "email": "poststelle@04125313.schule.bwl.de",
  "website": null,
  "tablet_tranche": null,
  "tablet_platform": null,
  "tablet_branches": null,
  "tablet_trades": null,
  "lat": 48.80094,
  "lng": 10.18761,
  "official": 0,
  "branches": [
    {
      "branch_id": 12110,
      "acronym": "GS",
      "description_long": "Grundschule"
    }
  ],
  "trades": []
}
```

I got the code via Chrome Inspector Network and requested the URL per Postman. My problem is, that I just get the Info for one school, and I can't find out how to request all the schools.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the correct endpoint:

```
https://schulfinder.kultus-bw.de/api/schools?distance=1&outposts=1&owner=&school_kind=&term=&types=&work_schedule=&_=1675079497084
```

That will give you a `list` of schools, that could be used to request further data via your endpoint from question (https://schulfinder.kultus-bw.de/api/school?...) using the `uuid`.

```
[{"uuid":"50de01a4-503d-44d1-af4b-a6031a022b85","outpost_number":"0","name":"Grundschule Aach","city":"Aach","lat":47.84399,"lng":8.85067,"official":0,"marker_class":"marker green","marker_label":"G","website":null},{"uuid":"8818037f-9aed-4860-b42e-8a49b1403c02","outpost_number":"0","name":"Braunenbergschule Grundschule Wasseralfingen","city":"Aalen","lat":48.8612,"lng":10.11191,"official":0,"marker_class":"marker green","marker_label":"G","website":null},...]
```

*Be aware, that the result is limited to 500 and you have to use and filters  and combine results to get all of them.*:

> Das Suchlimit wurde erreicht. Mehr als 500 Treffer werden nicht angezeigt. Bitte verfeinern Sie Ihre Suche indem Sie z. B. einen Ort angeben.

##### Example

```
import requests

url = 'https://schulfinder.kultus-bw.de/api/schools?distance=1&outposts=1&owner=&school_kind=&term=&types=&work_schedule=&_=1675079497084'

data = []

for uuid in [item['uuid'] for item in requests.get(url).json()]:
    url = url = f'https://schulfinder.kultus-bw.de/api/school?uuid={uuid}&_=1675072758525'
    data.append(
        requests.get(url).json()
    )

data
```

##### Output

```
[{'outpost_number': '0', 'name': 'Grundschule Aach', 'street': 'Schulstr.', 'house_number': '5', 'postcode': '78267', 'city': 'Aach', 'phone': '+4977741442', 'fax': None, 'email': 'poststelle@04146900.schule.bwl.de', 'website': None, 'tablet_tranche': None, 'tablet_platform': None, 'tablet_branches': None, 'tablet_trades': None, 'lat': 47.84399, 'lng': 8.85067, 'official': 0, 'branches': [{'branch_id': 12110, 'acronym': 'GS', 'description_long': 'Grundschule'}], 'trades': []}, {'outpost_number': '0', 'name': 'Braunenbergschule Grundschule Wasseralfingen', 'street': 'Steinstr.', 'house_number': '38', 'postcode': '73433', 'city': 'Aalen', 'phone': '+49736197700', 'fax': '+497361977019', 'email': 'poststelle@04125362.schule.bwl.de', 'website': 'http://www.braunenbergschule.de', 'tablet_tranche': None, 'tablet_platform': None, 'tablet_branches': None, 'tablet_trades': None, 'lat': 48.8612, 'lng': 10.11191, 'official': 0, 'branches': [{'branch_id': 12110, 'acronym': 'GS', 'description_long': 'Grundschule'}], 'trades': []},...]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Now I can extract every uuid for further data. Do you have any idea how I can use the list of the uuids to get all the data? Was your idea to use every uuid with the get link like "https://schulfinder.kultus-bw.de/api/school?uuid=81af189c-7bc0-44a3-8c9f-73e6d6e50fdb&_=1675072758525" and then change the uuid? Like using a while loop and insert every uuid in that link?

Comment: That was exactly the idea behind it, just adapt the example in my answer so that it meets your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [the answer already given](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75284070/18657410).

To get all the search criteria for the GET request to the API, you can parse the main page contents using [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) you've already imported:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

search_page_url = "https://schulfinder.kultus-bw.de"
page_contents = requests.request("GET", search_page_url).text

parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(page_contents, features="html.parser")
input_elements = parsed_html.body.find_all('input')
search_params = list(map(lambda x: (x.get('name'), x.get('type'), x.get('value')), input_elements))
```

`search_params` contains tuples of a name, type, and value. It should give you insights into parameters and their possible values.